# Trying to register a compile srcipt but src does not exist and I actually have it on my public folder, what do I do?? REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, src, npm-run

So I registered a compile script in package.json:

```
"compile": "babel src --out-dir public",
```

and when I put in git CMD npm run compile (my compile script) it is supposed to run it, but instead it gives me an error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy7FF.png)
I'm studying the Pro MERN stack 2nd Edition Book and I'm stuck in that part, it says is not necessary to use npx "don’t need the npx prefix because npm automatically figures out the location of commands
that are part of any locally installed packages"
And I don't know what to do now :(

I've tried use the `npm run compile` in the public folder directly and in the src folder but the error keep appearing and also tried moving my App.js inside src, here's my folder architecture right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ClA.png

Comment: Please insert errors as text in your question, for better web indexing/search and reading flow for SO users.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, there was a problem with the folder organization in my project, my src folder was inside my public folder and that's wrong, it should be at the same level as public.